# Allow only hexadecimal html entities

Tags: php, html, html-entities, hex

Got a forum and posting HTML is forbidden.
However, some users would like to have the possibility to post some symbolic signs, hexadecimal html entities, such as:

```
&#128151;
```

See: http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%92%97 for more info.

My questions are:

1. Is this safe to allow them such symbols at all (XSS, etc..)?
2. What's the best function to use, to allow it? Actually the symbolic html entities appear as plain text.
3. I want to disallow members using `&amp;` or `&raquo;` and so on, so just html-entities starting with &# and followed by a number plus the semicolon at the end.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: posting html entities is definitely not an issue. I'd just write a regex which replaces the ampersand in all the sequences which don't match the `&#\d+;` sequence.

Comment: @bwoebi Would you please provide a full example as an answer? Guess you are talking about preg_replace, right?

Comment: The example in the question is not an hexadecimal entity; such entities have the letter `x` (or `X`).

Comment: Re question 1: “safe” in which sense? Re question 2: “best” by which criteria? And 3 is not a question. Moreover, the question does not describe how the user input is processed now, so we cannot know how the processing would be intercepted by the added rules. And if you want to let users input special characters, which seems to be the intent here, consider adding a widget for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer is to use jQueries .text method to add the message to your forum message element.
Although you will have to change how your forum creates the message structure.

You can safely add any sequence of characters and none of them will be interpreted by the browser as HTML.

Example:

```
$('#message_text').text(naughty_msg_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this safe to allow them such symbols at all (XSS, etc..)?

No, this is never safe. For example, `&amp;` is just a convenient alias for `&#38;`, which is still an ampsersand. Similarly `&#60;` is a lesser-than sign, and thus 'naively' allowing numeric HTML-entities can still open up an XSS attack surface, if you forget this during processing.

You could consider only allowing numeric symbols outside the main ASCII table (128+), which would be more safe.

> What's the best function to use, to allow it? Actually the symbolic html entities appear as plain text.

Considering the above function, `preg_replace_callback` is a good candidate, as it allows you to test the content before (dis)allowing it.

This also answers the third question, as you can just test for numbers in the regexp.

Comment: This is why I asked for hexadezimal characters only, should have six numbers behind the &#. Could you also please provide an answer with an example of $string for better understanding?